# Not helping, found these else where

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datatable, backend

account_from    account_to
1001    1003
1008    1011
1050    1051

Comment: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/querying-with-transactsql-10530

Comment: Looks like you should delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join of a table against itself using aliases. That might be what you are looking for?

```
select * from Trades t1, Trades t2 where
t1.timestamp-t2.timestamp<10 and
...
```

Comment: Hi Paul. The SQL you have written is that giving the outcome the book exercise has presented?